# Change tab using link or button in tab content

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have a page that has tabbed content, this is working well, however on one of the content sections I want to have a link or button that points another tab on the page.  When click on link I would like it to change to the tab.

Below it the extracted code on the page:

HTML

```
<div class="my-tabs">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="is-active"><a href="#tab-one">Tab One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-two">Tab Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-three">Tab Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <section class="tab-content is-active" id="tab-one">Section One Content <a href="#tab-three">link to Tab Three</a></section>
  <section class="tab-content" id="tab-two">Section Two Content</section>
  <section class="tab-content" id="tab-three">Section Three Content</section>
  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.is-active {
  display: block;
}
.tabs ul {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
}
.tabs li {
    display: block;
}
.tabs li.is-active a {
    border-bottom-color: #3273dc;
    color: #3273dc;
}
.tabs a {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #363636;
  color: #363636;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".my-tabs .tabs li");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".my-tabs .tab-content");

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    removeActiveTab();
    addActiveTab(tab);
  });
})

const removeActiveTab = () => {
  tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
}

const addActiveTab = tab => {
  tab.classList.add("is-active");
  const href = tab.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
  const matchingSection = document.querySelector(href);
  matchingSection.classList.add("is-active");
}
```

I have tried using the same a href link that is in the tab within the content area but it does not change to the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you didn't write any logic or attach any listener which triggers when clicking on *"link to tab three"*. Only adding attribute `href="tab-three"` will not do the job.
You already implemented a click listener on all tabs anchors and you need to do the same for *"link to tab three"*

Here is what I did-

1. Attach an event listener on the *"link to tab three"* element.
2. Parse the `href` attribute this link is requesting to redirect.
3. Find the tab of that parsed `href` attribute, and find its parent element, the `li` tag.
   (**Why find the parent?** because the `activeTab` function is working on the anchor's parent element, `li`.)
4. Called the same function `activeTab` and pass the found `li` parent element.

Here is the working demo-

```js
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".my-tabs .tabs li");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".my-tabs .tab-content");
const extraLink = document.querySelector("#extraLink")

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    removeActiveTab();
    addActiveTab(tab);
  });
})

extraLink.addEventListener("click", e => {
  // remove previously active tab
  removeActiveTab();
  // find the element
  let href = e.target.getAttribute("href")
  let el = document.querySelector(`a[href="${href}"]`).parentElement;
  // make it active.
  addActiveTab(el)
});

const removeActiveTab = () => {
  tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
}

const addActiveTab = tab => {
  tab.classList.add("is-active");
  const href = tab.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
  const matchingSection = document.querySelector(href);
  matchingSection.classList.add("is-active");
}
```

```css
.tab-content {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content.is-active {
  display: block;
}
.tabs ul {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
}
.tabs li {
    display: block;
}
.tabs li.is-active a {
    border-bottom-color: #3273dc;
    color: #3273dc;
}
.tabs a {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs a:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #363636;
  color: #363636;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-tabs">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="is-active"><a href="#tab-one">Tab One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-two">Tab Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-three">Tab Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="tab-content is-active" id="tab-one">Section One Content <a href="#tab-three" id="extraLink">link to Tab Three</a></section>
  <section class="tab-content" id="tab-two">Section Two Content</section>
  <section class="tab-content" id="tab-three">Section Three Content</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote the solution in this JSFiddle, all you got to do is tidy up/rename the vars but you can see this working example as reference: https://jsfiddle.net/ilanpatao/ug240awz/133/

HTML:

```
<div class="my-tabs">
  <nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="is-active"><a href="#tab-one">Tab One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab-two">Tab Two</a></li>
      <li class="tab3"><a href="#tab-three">Tab Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section class="tab-content is-active" id="tab-one">Section One Content <a href="#tab-three" id="toTab3">link to Tab Three</a></section>
  <section class="tab-content" id="tab-two">Section Two Content</section>
  <section class="tab-content" id="tab-three">Section Three Content</section>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".my-tabs .tabs li");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".my-tabs .tab-content");

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    removeActiveTab();
    addActiveTab(tab);
  });
})

const removeActiveTab = () => {
  tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
  sections.forEach(section => {
    section.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
}

const addActiveTab = tab => {
  tab.classList.add("is-active");
  const href = tab.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
  const matchingSection = document.querySelector(href);
  matchingSection.classList.add("is-active");
}   

const tab_button = document.getElementById('toTab3');
tab_button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.classList.remove("is-active");
     const matchingSection = document.querySelector(".my-tabs .tab-content");
    matchingSection.classList.remove("is-active");
  });
     const tab3 = document.getElementById('tab-three');
    tab3.classList.add("is-active");
    const li3 = document.getElementsByClassName("tab3");
    li3[0].classList.add("is-active");
});
```

So all I did was target the the elements to remove the is-active class and push it to tab-three specifically; there's a much elegant way to do this btw but this is a quick illustration how your existing code makes up the solution for this link.